# Quantlib specifying derived classes by name string

Tags: python, quantlib

I am using quantlib-python version 1.10.

I would like to know if there is

1. a way to get a list of available implementations for a given superclass. Let's say you want to have a list of all existing classes implementing the calendar class, such as TARGET, UnitedKingdom, ... . I know QuantLibXL has done something that is able to list implementations of superclasses, e.g. `=ohEnumeratedClass("class QuantLib::Interpolation")`. There even is a function that lists all superclasses that can be enumerated: `ohListEnumeratedClasses()`
2. a way to instantiate the implemented class by string. Let's say you want to have the TARGET calendar, is there a way to say something like `myCal = QuantLib.Calendar("TARGET")` (I know this does not work... but I would like to know how this COULD work). I know QuantLibXL has done something like that, e.g. `qlCalendarAdvance("TARGET",TODAY(),"2D")`
3. a way to test if a given object is of type [Calendar, DayCounter, Implementation, ...]. I know I can do `isinstance(a,QuantLib.Calendar)`. But is there a way to do something like `isinstance(a,QuantLib.Interpolation)`, to test whether a is some interpolator, e.g. `a=QuantLib.Linear()` or `a=QuantLib.LogLinear()`

The calendar classes are just given as an example. For example, i would like to be able to instantiate a linear interpolator by string: something like `a=createQLInterpolator("Linear")`. I would also like to be able to do the same for calendars, DayCounters, Compoundings, Frequencies, Interpolators and so forth. I could implement something like this by hand if there were a way to

1. list possible implementations and
2. instantiate classes by string.

The possibility to check whether a given instance actually is of superclass Calendar would make flexible programming possible, where the user can pass either a string or a QuantLib class.

Thank you!